# Passing propData in vue jest is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm passing the propData in my jest test file in vue but it's not set the propData data to component instead it's giving error cannot read property of clouds of undefined my object is written right?.

my jest test file

```
import sideWeatherDetails from "@/components/sidemenu/sideWeatherDetails.vue";
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuex from "vuex";
window.alert = jest.fn();
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);
describe("check if convert temperature action is firing", () => {
  let actions;
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      convertToFarenheit: jest.fn()
    };
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions
    });
  });

  it("convertToFarenheit is firing when checkbox is checked", () => {
    const propData = {
      clouds: { all: 40 },
      visibility: 2,
      main: { humidity: 40 },
      wind: { speed: 1.33 }
    };
    const wrapper = mount(sideWeatherDetails, { store, localVue, propData });
    const checkbox = wrapper.find({ ref: "convertTemp" });
    checkbox.setChecked();
    expect(actions.convertToFarenheit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

my component that i'm testing

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 class="weather-head">Weather Details</h2>
    <div class="side-info-value" v-if="data">
      <p>
        <span class="side-key data-key">Cloudy</span>
        <span class="data-value">{{ data.clouds.all }}%</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-info-value" v-if="data">
      <p>
        <span class="side-key data-key">Humidity</span>
        <span class="data-value">{{ data.main.humidity }}%</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-info-value" v-if="data">
      <p>
        <span class="side-key data-key">Visibility</span>
        <span class="data-value">{{ data.visibility / 1000 }} km</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-info-value" v-if="data">
      <p>
        <span class="side-key data-key">Wind</span>
        <span class="data-value">{{ data.wind.speed }} m/s</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-info-value">
      <p>
        <span class="side-key data-key">In Farenheit</span>
        <span class="data-value">
          <input ref="convertTemp" type="checkbox" @change="convertToFar()" />
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  props: ["data"],
  methods: {
    convertToFar() {
      if (this.$refs.convertTemp.checked) {
        this.convertToFarenheit();
      } else {
        this.convertToCelsius();
      }
    },
    ...mapActions(["convertToFarenheit", "convertToCelsius"])
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. You need **propsData**, not *propData* you have currently.

```
it("convertToFarenheit is firing when checkbox is checked", () => {
  const propsData = {
    clouds: { all: 40 },
    visibility: 2,
    main: { humidity: 40 },
    wind: { speed: 1.33 }
  };
  const wrapper = mount(sideWeatherDetails, { store, localVue, propsData });
  const checkbox = wrapper.find({ ref: "convertTemp" });
  checkbox.setChecked();
  expect(actions.convertToFarenheit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: so name is fixed i can't change it?

Comment: if i remove v-if="data" and add propsData it still throws the error  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clouds' of undefined"

Comment: check it here here's my github repo https://github.com/naveenkash/vue-weather this file name is sideweatherdetails.vue and it's test is under test/sidemenu_test

Comment: can you please help me with this